# How do I insert data into multiple tables in single query - Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli-multi-query

I have 8 query's to insert into 8 tables. I have tried with this But no use

```
$mysql_db_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_db_user = "root";
$mysql_db_password = "";
$mysql_db_database = "emp";

$con = mysqli_connect($mysql_db_hostname, $mysql_db_user, $mysql_db_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysqli_select_db($con, $mysql_db_database) or die("<div class='loginmsg'>Could not select database</div>");

if(mysqli_multi_query($con,"INSERT INTO t_emp (`e_id`,``,``) VALUES ('','',''); INSERT INTO t_emp_add (`e_id`,``,``) VALUES ('','',''); INSERT INTO t_emp_att (`e_id`,``,``) VALUES ('','',''); INSERT INTO t_emp_dep (`e_id`,``,``) VALUES ('','','');.....(etc);"))
{
 echo "Inserted";
}
else{
 echo "Not Inserted";
 }
```

Is there any method to store into multiple tables..?

Comment: Any error messages? What is your actual query?

Comment: That isn't how multi query works. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php or this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp

Comment: you also have a syntax error here echo "Not Inserted" and you need to use proper error handling http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: you can use trigger https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: My above comment about the syntax error should have been and/or contained http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Are you using a MYISAM or INNODB database?

Comment: I am using INNODB database

Comment: Then you woudl be better advised to use a transaction rather than a multi_query, as any one of you 8 INSERTS might fail and you would not know which one had failed and your database would be in a mess

Comment: How do I implement "transaction".?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) PHP/5.4.16

Comment: Sorry one more question and what version of MYSQL

Comment: mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026

Comment: Are you using WAMPServer 2.4 by any chance?

Comment: Pity, I am not sure what mysqlind 5.0.10 means. Is that MySQL 5.0.10 To use transactions you have to be using MYSQL 5.6 or greater

Comment: Ok I'll upgrade to 5.6.

Comment: Careful you do not loose you databases in the upgrade

Comment: Ok, please let me know how to use transactions

Comment: @RiggsFolly, `mysqlind 5.0.10` would mean the Native Driver seen thru calling `phpinfo();` in php

Comment: @Drew Thanks I sort of knew that and was trying to get her to look for that actual MYSQL version number rather than the Driver version.

Comment: It all in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) Start here

Comment: `show variables where variable_name ='version'` @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't support multi-table insertion in a single INSERT statement.

The problem that you are trying to solve by using a "single query" is solved by using *transactions:*

```
mysqli_query($con,"BEGIN");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tab1 (col1, col2) VALUES('1', '2')");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tab2 (col1, col2,col3) VALUES(1,2,3)");
mysqli_query($con,"COMMIT");
```

Comment: I am new to php and mysql. can you please elaborate how can I use this code means where do I insert connection string and how to implement if condition for successful insertions and failures

Comment: there is nothing to suggest that this is transactional, especially for an OP that says she is new to php and mysql. Is it a bad idea, no.

Answer (score 0):

No, MySQL hasn't expression for inserting by one query in multiple tables.

If you want, you can use MySQL [stored procedures or functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) and/or use [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) for that.

Comment: @Machavity OP posted the same question now http://stackoverflow.com/q/33583542/ and it has been suggested she uses just that. That's a repost/duplicate as per how Stack sees it.

Comment: I see no problem with this answer

Answer (score 0):

As the question was closed in other posting, I'll put this here - to create a stored procedure:-

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `spInsertTemp`( IN `p_emp_no` INT, IN `p_e_id` INT, IN `p_att_s_no` INT, IN `p_dep_s_no` INT )
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
begin
    insert into `t_emp` (`emp_s_no`,`e_id` ) values ( p_emp_no, p_e_id );
    insert into `t_emp_add` ( `e_id` ) values ( p_e_id );
    insert into `t_emp_att` (`att_s_no`,`e_id` ) values ( p_att_s_no, p_e_id );
    insert into `t_emp_dep` ( `dep_s_no`, `e_id`) values ( p_dep_s_no, p_e_id );
end $$;
delimiter ;
```

Run that in your gui, use like:-

```
$sql='call `spInsertTemp`(1,2,4,5);';
```

Comment: $sql='call `spInsertTemp`(1,2,4,5);';
what are these 1,2,3,4,5..?

Comment: They my friend are example parameter values that represent the various parameters of the storedprocedure. The sp has 4 params, hence 4 values

Comment: @RamRaider I think you're in for a long haul with this one. I'm not insulting this person by saying this, but it's obvious that she hasn't grasped the SQL concept. In her other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/33583542/, she mentions a form *"@RiggsFolly first time means when I submit the form at first time ( First record ) – angel"* and there is no code to support the question, nor does she check why it failed. `echo "Not Inserted";` does nothing to tell her the REAL reason as to why her query failed. I doubt her questions will ever be resolved. I sincerely wish her well.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You could well be right ~ I realise too late alas! Let me join you in wishing her well

Comment: @RamRaider I know I'm right; I feel it in my bones ;-) But I'll upvote for your trouble and that is a good example of using procedures. *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `After Insert Trigger` to insert record in multiple table. It will automatically fired when a insert statement is excuted within that database.